Google Apps Script exceeds execution time because there are too many cells to copy from one Sheet to another
I have a routine task to copy data from one Sheet to another Sheet. My source Sheet usually has a varying number of cells but it's always around 300k rows and 6 columns. All the data copied is necessary, and there are no unnecessary cells.
function CopyData() {
  // Open the source spreadsheet by its ID and get the active sheet
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1bRyR7l0WR4EoeBukxX5teR_zi9M96I19qqz_0MCQcmE').getActiveSheet();
  
  // Get the last row and column of the source sheet to determine the range of data
  var lastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();
  
  // Define the range of the data in the source sheet
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn);
  
  // Get the values from the defined range in the source sheet
  var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
  
  // Open the target spreadsheet by its ID and get the active sheet
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1FgLQ8OxDSNmXLTmrWNIG3q5EH4TeuBUXmBKpAZ2Wck4').getActiveSheet();
  
  // Get the last row of the target sheet just because I need it like that
  var tLastRow = targetSS.getLastRow();
  
  // Insert a new row after the last row in the target sheet
  targetSS.insertRowAfter(tLastRow);
  
  // Set the values in the new row range in the target sheet with the values from the source sheet
  targetSS.getRange(tLastRow + 1, 1, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length)
    .setValues(sourceValues);
}


Previously, everything worked fine for this amount of data, but recently the script started stopping because of exceeded execution time. Is there any way to optimize my script without using the Sheets API with its advanced methods?

Error
Excede maximum execution time


From Is there any way to optimize my script without using the Sheets API with its advanced methods?, you cannot use Sheets API. Is my understanding correct?

instead of targetSS.insertRowAfter targetSS.insertRowsAfter(afterPosition, howMany) - this will add the rows in the targetSS AND then, you can set the values. If the problem persists, check if the targetSS has empty, non-usable columns (i.e. delete the columns not needed in targetSS), then, change your code to divide the sourceValues and batch-insert by chunks.

You can explore copyTo method of class range (in any of its flavors) https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination
Yo can change the way you get sourceRange using method getDataRange of class sheets
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange
To evaluate the convenience of any option you can use console time log
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/timelog_static

Provide some sample data using Blank Sheet Maker so others can see the behavior and test and try getDataRange as JPP suggested

what if you would run your script in batches like:
function CopyData() {
  // Constants for batch size to process data in chunks
  var BATCH_SIZE = 50000; // Adjust the batch size if needed

  // Open the source spreadsheet by its ID and get the active sheet
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1bRyR7l0WR4EoeBukxX5teR_zi9M96I19qqz_0MCQcmE').getActiveSheet();
  
  // Get the last row and column of the source sheet to determine the range of data
  var lastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();
  
  // Open the target spreadsheet by its ID and get the active sheet
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1FgLQ8OxDSNmXLTmrWNIG3q5EH4TeuBUXmBKpAZ2Wck4').getActiveSheet();
  
  // Initialize row counter
  var startRow = 1;
  
  // Loop through the data in chunks
  while (startRow <= lastRow) {
    // Calculate the end row for the current batch
    var endRow = Math.min(startRow + BATCH_SIZE - 1, lastRow);
    
    // Define the range of the data for the current batch
    var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, endRow - startRow + 1, lastColumn);
    
    // Get the values from the defined range in the source sheet
    var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
    
    // Get the last row of the target sheet
    var tLastRow = targetSS.getLastRow();
    
    // Insert a new row after the last row in the target sheet
    targetSS.insertRowsAfter(tLastRow, sourceValues.length);
    
    // Set the values in the new row range in the target sheet with the values from the source sheet
    targetSS.getRange(tLastRow + 1, 1, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length)
      .setValues(sourceValues);
    
    // Update the start row for the next batch
    startRow = endRow + 1;
  }
}

or detect nearing the limit and resume from where it was interrupted:
function CopyData() {
  var BATCH_SIZE = 50000; // Adjust the batch size if needed
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

  // Get the start row from script properties or default to 1
  var startRow = parseInt(scriptProperties.getProperty('startRow')) || 1;

  // Open the source spreadsheet by its ID and get the active sheet
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1bRyR7l0WR4EoeBukxX5teR_zi9M96I19qqz_0MCQcmE').getActiveSheet();

  // Get the last row and column of the source sheet to determine the range of data
  var lastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();

  // Open the target spreadsheet by its ID and get the active sheet
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1FgLQ8OxDSNmXLTmrWNIG3q5EH4TeuBUXmBKpAZ2Wck4').getActiveSheet();

  // Loop through the data in chunks
  while (startRow <= lastRow) {
    // Calculate the end row for the current batch
    var endRow = Math.min(startRow + BATCH_SIZE - 1, lastRow);

    // Define the range of the data for the current batch
    var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, endRow - startRow + 1, lastColumn);

    // Get the values from the defined range in the source sheet
    var sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();

    // Get the last row of the target sheet
    var tLastRow = targetSS.getLastRow();

    // Insert new rows after the last row in the target sheet
    targetSS.insertRowsAfter(tLastRow, sourceValues.length);

    // Set the values in the new row range in the target sheet with the values from the source sheet
    targetSS.getRange(tLastRow + 1, 1, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length)
      .setValues(sourceValues);

    // Update the start row for the next batch
    startRow = endRow + 1;

    // Check if script runtime is nearing its limit
    if (ScriptApp.getScriptTriggers().length == 0) {
      scriptProperties.setProperty('startRow', startRow);
      ScriptApp.newTrigger('CopyData')
               .timeBased()
               .after(1)
               .create();
      return;
    }
  }
  // Clear the startRow property when the job is done
  scriptProperties.deleteProperty('startRow');
}

